# How to obtain information about the IP address of the user who made commit to the github repository

Tags: github, github-api

#### It it possible to obtain the IP address of the user who made a commit in the github repo?

I'm trying the commits API call, but it doesn't contain any information about that.

```bash
curl --request GET --url "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/commits/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  --header "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
```

#### output

```json
{
  "sha": "b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10",
  "node_id": "C_kwDOKRgIVtoAKGI0NmZmZmVlYWM2OTg5MjQ3MGVlYTE0NjkyYzIxOGVhN2EwOWFjMTA",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "FName LName",
      "email": "email@domain.com",
      "date": "2023-09-09T21:05:38Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "FName LName",
      "email": "email@domain.com",
      "date": "2023-09-09T21:05:38Z"
    },
    "message": "feat: test ip",
    "tree": {
      "sha": "912b9f298c81c371c7da2070bc860964d124cfeb",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/git/trees/912b9f298c81c371c7da2070bc860964d124cfeb"
    },
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/git/commits/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10",
    "comment_count": 0,
    "verification": {
      "verified": false,
      "reason": "unsigned",
      "signature": null,
      "payload": null
    }
  },
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/commits/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/org/test-public-repo/commit/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/commits/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10/comments",
  "author": {
    "login": "github-user",
    "id": 11111,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjcwODIyNzEw",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/70822710?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/github-user",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "committer": {
    "login": "github-user",
    "id": 11111,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjcwODIyNzEw",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11111?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/github-user",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/github-user/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "parents": [
    {
      "sha": "26c26f8856cd81d9f9144e6654897320f4b9f575",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/commits/26c26f8856cd81d9f9144e6654897320f4b9f575",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/org/test-public-repo/commit/26c26f8856cd81d9f9144e6654897320f4b9f575"
    }
  ],
  "stats": {
    "total": 1,
    "additions": 1,
    "deletions": 0
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "sha": "e389600420ded46e657d418951fa716c9f18bb12",
      "filename": "README.md",
      "status": "modified",
      "additions": 1,
      "deletions": 0,
      "changes": 1,
      "blob_url": "https://github.com/org/test-public-repo/blob/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10/README.md",
      "raw_url": "https://github.com/org/test-public-repo/raw/b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10/README.md",
      "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/test-public-repo/contents/README.md?ref=b46fffeeac69892470eea14692c218ea7a09ac10",
      "patch": "@@ -2,3 +2,4 @@\n test\n \n ii\n+aa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible.  First of all, GitHub doesn't know the IP address of the person who created the commit, only the person who pushed it, which may not be the same.  In addition, a person can have many IP addresses (home, work, school, coffee shop) and GitHub could only know the IP address that the person who pushed it was using at the given time.

Also, in general, exposing that would be problematic from a personal data standpoint, since people don't have to use a real name or a real email address to commit on GitHub, and many people would be uncomfortable exposing their home or work IP.  Think of situations where people have engaged in harassment or swatting against others for various reasons, or users in countries with repressive governments.  It might also violate various privacy laws, such as GDPR, to reveal that information without the user's consent.